# IValueConverter for visibility binding in WPF is never called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I want to bind the visibility property of a control in WPF to a boolean value.
I wrote a Converter based on `IValueConverter`:

```
namespace MyApp.Converter
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {            
            if ((Boolean)(value)==true)
            {
                return "Visible";
            }
            return "Collapsed";
        }

        public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And tried both: to define the converter in App.xaml and in the Window.Resources of the Window itself:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converter"
...
<Window.Resources>
    <Converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

alternative in App.xaml:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converter"
...
<Application.Resources>
    <Converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Using the Converter for the visibility property compiles - but the converter is never called and thus the visibility never changes:

```
<Label Visibility="{Binding ShowCirle,  Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

The binding itself seems ok - since the output of ShowCircle in a label updates correctly:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ShowCircle}"></Label>
```

So, what am I missing? The build compiles without errors, starts, but the binding only updates the string (for debug purposes) but not the visibility - and a breakpoint in the converter itself is never hit.

Comment: Why does your converter return a string? Visibility is an enum. Have your converter return a value from [that enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.visibility?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and it should work fine

Comment: Your example with Visibility has `ShowCirle` instead of `ShowCircle`. It's hard to know whether that's a bug in actual code or just the post. It's not clear to me why you're returning strings rather than visibilities though. It's also not clear why you've created your own BoolToVisibilityConverter when [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) already exists...

Comment: `return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;`

Comment: Thanks! It was the misspelling of "ShowCirle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your converter should not return a `string` it should be `Visiblity.Visible` or `Visibility.Collapsed`.

To check if your Bindings are correct take a look at the Output-Window when debugging. If you see a Binding-Error (20,40 not sure which one) with your Property-Name then something is wrong with your binding. Maybe just a missspelling of the property.